# Failed to install *.apk on device 'emulator-5554' error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

```
[2015-01-21 14:27:38 - FirstAndroidProject] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Android_5.0.1'

[2015-01-21 14:27:51 - FirstAndroidProject] New emulator found: emulator-5554

[2015-01-21 14:27:51 - FirstAndroidProject] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...

[2015-01-21 14:30:52 - FirstAndroidProject] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'

[2015-01-21 14:30:52 - FirstAndroidProject] Uploading FirstAndroidProject.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'

[2015-01-21 14:30:53 - FirstAndroidProject] Installing FirstAndroidProject.apk...

[2015-01-21 14:33:00 - FirstAndroidProject] Failed to install FirstAndroidProject.apk on device 'emulator-5554!

[2015-01-21 14:33:00 - FirstAndroidProject] (null)

[2015-01-21 14:33:01 - FirstAndroidProject] Launch canceled!
```

This is my very first `Android app`. I tried every possible way explained in solutions provided in stackoverflow.com but every time I launched the app I get the above error in the console. 
But on every time I opened the icon in the menu list in the emulator after the above message is displayed, the app opens successfully. What is actually meant by the above error?

Answer (score 0):

Kill your adb **manually** in the your processes after close the emulator, restart your eclipse..

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project and restart the emulator. Then, try launching the app again.